# Search name in Array of class object

Tags: c++

I want to implement search functionality. I am taking input from first name from user. After input i want search by first name and i asking user to input first name to search but it didn't working can anyone tell where i am wrong. My code is below

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define MAX 10

class Person {
private:
    string first_name;   


    void setFirstName(string name)
    {
        first_name = name;
    }

    string getFirstName()
    {
        return first_name;
    }

    void inputfunction()
    {
        string FirstName;
        cout << "Enter the first name:";
        cin >> FirstName;
        setFirstName(FirstName);
    }

    void displayInputInfo(){
        cout << "First Name:  " << getFirstName() << endl;

    }

};
int main()
{
    Person obj[MAX];        
    int loop;


    obj[0].inputfunction();
    obj[1].inputfunction();

    string Name;
    cout << "Enter Name to serach";
    cin >> Name;
    for (loop = 0; loop< MAX; loop++){

        if (obj[loop].getFirstName == Name)
        {
            cout << "Index:" << loop;
            break;
        }

    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "It didn't work" is not a good description of the problem. Please tell us exactly what your code is supposed to do and exactly what happens when you run it.

Comment: I have already told what it suppose to do. It simple I want to search by first name but it giving error in serching part

Comment: What error? Search for the name in where?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two errors in your code.

First, you have declared **all** members of your `Person` class as `private` - which means you can't call the functions from outside the class, as in:

```cpp
obj[0].inputfunction();
```

To fix this, add the `public:` statement before the definition of the first member function (i.e. on the line before `void setFirstName(string name)`).

The second problem (which is mostly likely a simple 'typo') is in your call to `getFirstName` inside the `for` loop. This call is missing the (empty) parentheses that *must* be given when you invoke a function (with no argument). So, use this:

```cpp
    if (obj[loop].getFirstName() == Name) { // Note the () after the function name!
        //...
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: it giving error `error C3867: 'Person::getFirstName': function call missing argument list; use '&Person::getFirstName' to create a pointer to member2`

Comment: @Azeem - Like I said, this is because you don't have the `()` after `getFirstName` - the second of the two errors I addressed. These create an empty argument list.

Comment: No problem! I would also recommend to and some `<< std::endl` (newline/flush) after your output lines.

Comment: one more thing i want ask can i take search functionality inside the class instead of main

Comment: Of course you can! Maybe a member function that looks something like this: `int getIndex(std::string name) {...` that returns the index (if found) or `-1` if not found. But adding any more such detail would warrant a new question.